# Setting an image rendition to center crop in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm working on a CMS build (Python, Django, Graphene, Wagtail).

I know wagtail offers a get_rendition that can resize an image to fit given dimensions (Similar to CSS background-size: cover).

The options that appear to be available are based on resizing:
https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3.1/topics/images/using_in_templates.html#image-tag-alt

But I'm looking for just a center crop with no resizing.